# Scrolling a UIView along with UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableview in which `UITableViewCell` contains a textfield. When user tap on the textfield and keyboard appears, I scroll to the tapped in row after setting proper content inset.

Now, I have a UIView shown on top of my table view which I need to adjust accordingly when table scrolls.

To do this, I implemented `scrollViewDidScroll:` method as below. While this works in certain situations, it do not work or give random results in some situations. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)iScrollView {
    if (self.hollowView) {
        CGPoint offset = iScrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect hollowViewFrame = self.hollowView.hollowFrame;
        hollowViewFrame.origin.y += self.previousOffset - offset.y;
        self.previousOffset = offset.y;
        [self.hollowView resetToFrame:hollowViewFrame];
    }
} 

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)iNotification {
    self.previousOffset = 0.0;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Try to use `IQKeyboardManager` manage keyboard. It's easy to use

Comment: If you are using `autoLayout` you should not change view position by manipulating its frame.

Comment: If you want to scroll the view along with the table view why not use tableViewheader. Put your View into the tableViewHeader and the view will scroll along the tableView as the table scrolls

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for scrolling table in ios.

```
-(void )keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
 {

    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin =[keyboardInfovalueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    keyBoardHeight = keyboardFrameBegin.CGRectValue.size.height;
    vwSendBottomSpaceContraint.constant = keyBoardHeight
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottomAnimated) withObject:nil  afterDelay:0.1];

}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{

      vwSendBottomSpaceContraint.constant = 0;
      [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottomAnimated) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}

-(void)scrollToBottomAnimated
{

       NSInteger rows = [tableview numberOfRowsInSection:0];

       if(rows > 0)
       {
         [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rows - 1 inSection:0]                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottomanimated:YES];       
       }

}
```

Comment: No, I am not looking for scrolling the table when keyboard show up. This I'm already doing. I have another hollow view on top of table view which I want to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll the both view simultaneously then you should have to take both views with same size and in following method just set the scrollview content offset to them. It will surly work

```
enter code here - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)iScrollView {
if (self.scrollView) // Check for the scrolled view 
{
    // Set the Tableview offset directly
  tableview.contentOffset = iScrollView.contentOffset  
}
else {
   //Set view scroll as per tableview scroll
       view.contentOffset = iScrollView.contentOffset   } }
```

//Note :- Make sure view should be scrollview type or if view is getting scared or shows black screen

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use this library:

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

It will handle the position of Views when tapped on a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

So, this piece worked for me for anyone who is struggling with same situation:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)iScrollView {
    if (self.hollowView) {
        CGRect frame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:self.expandedCellIndexPath];
        frame.origin.y -= self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
        [self.hollowView resetToFrame:frame];
    }
}
```